Toggle between normal mode and full screen in Win32
I created a function that toggles the window between normal mode and full screen. If the width parameter equals 0, the window will be in full screen mode. Otherwise, it will be in the normal screen mode and will depend on its size in the height and width parameters.
// width equle 0 = fullscreen, other 0 = normal window
void CL_fulscrn(HWND hwnd, const unsigned short W, const unsigned short H) {
    if (!W) {
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, 0);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP);
        MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES), GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), VERTRES), 0);
    }
    else {
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED);
        MoveWindow(hwnd, (GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES) - W) / 2, (GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), VERTRES) - H) / 2, W, H, 0);
    }
}

when in full screen mode, the window is fine, but when switching to normal mode: enter image description here
So why?
I tried to change the MoveWindow function to the SetWindowPos function:
// width equle 0 = fullscreen, other 0 = normal window
void CL_fulscrn(HWND hwnd, const unsigned short W, const unsigned short H) {
    if (!W) {
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, 0);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES), GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), VERTRES), SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
    else {
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, (GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES) - W) / 2, (GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), VERTRES) - H) / 2, W, H, SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
}

But same problem.
And I tried this:
void CL_fulscrn(HWND hwnd, const unsigned short W, const unsigned short H) {
    if (!W) {
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, 0);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP);
        // I tried this too, and same problem
        //SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES), GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), VERTRES), SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOZORDER);
         SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES), GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), VERTRES), SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
    else {
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED);
        // I tried this too, and same problem
        //SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, (GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES) - W) / 2, (GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), VERTRES) - H) / 2, W, H, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOZORDER);
         SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, (GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES) - W) / 2, (GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), VERTRES) - H) / 2, W, H, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
}



You need to pass SWP_FRAMECHANGED to indicate that you changed the nonclient area. (You also are leaking DCs. And you don't support multi-monitor.)

Related: Fullscreen vs Borderless window. Also, when I go to fullscreen, I first GetWindowRect() which I use to restore.

The problem is solved, As he said @Torrecto - MSFT, I just had to add WS_CAPTION with WS_SYSMENU.

As @Raymond Chen said, you need to pass SWP_FRAMECHANGED in SetWindowPos to indicate that you've already changed the nonclient area.
Edit1:
"Did you call WM_NCCALCSIZE in wndProc?"
"No, why I need it? And what do I write in the event?"
It's necessary. You need to see the meaning of SWP_FRAMECHANGED:
Applies new frame styles set using the SetWindowLong function. Sends a WM_NCCALCSIZE message to the window, even if the window's size is not being changed. If this flag is not specified, WM_NCCALCSIZE is sent only when the window's size is being changed.
We can reproduced it without WM_NCCALCSIZE.

Just return 0 in WM_NCCALCSIZE:
  case WM_NCCALCSIZE: {
        return 0;
    }

When wParam is TRUE, simply returning 0 without processing the NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS rectangles will cause the client area to resize to the size of the window, including the window frame. This will remove the window frame and caption items from your window, leaving only the client area displayed.
Edit2:
OP just want to show the title bar.
WS_SYSMENU: The window has a window menu on its title bar. The WS_CAPTION style must also be specified.

Thanks for reply, but it didn't solve the problem .

@M027 It still left the white area? How does the message loop work? Can you show a minimal reproducible sample?

I will add in my question.

@M027 Did you call WM_NCCALCSIZE in wndProc?

No, why I need it? And what do I write in the event?

@M027 I edited my answer. Check it again plz.

I think you didn't understand my question, I make function to toggle between full screen and normal mode, when it's in normal mode I want it to be with window frame (title bar, buttons maximize and minimize and close, you know), but comes is to be empty white bar, even though I added the styles to be it (WS_SYSMENU and WS_MAXIMIZEBOX and WS_MINIMIZEBOX), it still to be empty white bar.

@M027 So you just want to show the title bar. Because you didn't use WS_CAPTION. WS_SYSMENU means:  The window has a window menu on its title bar. The WS_CAPTION style must also be specified.
